# Insert special characters in the database with a bulk query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, special-characters

I need to insert a large amount of countries with corresponding information in a database. This works, but the special characters are inserted in the database as Ã¼ and Ã©, for example. How can I insert the countries in the database with the special characters (preferably by using the code below)?

Below is the code I use for this. I use a multi query, because there are multiple queries I run (the code below is only a fraction). As an example I put some countries with special characters (the real list is about 250 countries).

**Insert_countries.php:**

```
include 'mysql_connect.php';

// select database
    mysqli_select_db( $mysqli, 'my_database' );

// check connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_errno > 0 ) {
    trigger_error( 'Database connection failed: '  . $mysqli->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR );
}

// sql query
$sql = 'INSERT INTO countries (country_code_num, country_code_iso, country_en, country_nl, country_de, country_fr, country_continent, country_region, country_union) VALUES
        ("016", "AS", "American Samoa", "Amerikaans-Samoa", "Amerikanisch-Samoa", "Samoa américaine", "Oceania", "Polynesia", ""),
        ("020", "AD", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra (Fürstentum)", "Andorre (Principauté)", "Europa", "Southern Europe ", ""),
        ("044", "BS", "Bahamas", "Bahama\'s", "Bahamas", "Bahamas", "Americas", "Caribbean", ""),
        ("894", "ZM", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Sambia", "Zambie", "Africa", "Eastern Africa", "");';

// Execute multi query
if ( $mysqli->multi_query( $sql ) ) {
    do {
        if ( $res = $mysqli->store_result() ) {
            while ( $row = $res->fetch_row() ) {
                printf( "%s\n", $row[0] );
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        if ( $mysqli->more_results() ) {
            printf( "-----------------\n" );
        }
    }
    while ( $mysqli->next_result() );
}

$mysqli->close();
```

**EDIT:**

As requested (a part of) the create table statement and also the create database.

```
// create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";

// create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries ( 
        country_code_num INT(3) NOT NULL,
        country_code_iso VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
        country_en VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
        country_nl VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
        country_de VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
        country_fr VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
        country_continent VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        country_region VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        country_union VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ( country_code_num ));";
```

Comment: It depends. Are you consistently using UTF-8? Do you use [mysqli::set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)? Please post your CREATE TABLE statement too.

Comment: I think I have consistently used UTF-8. Haven't used mysqli::set_charset though.

Comment: Fire up a [mysqli::get_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-charset.php) call and have a look at the result. Please note the note to mysqli::set_charset: *This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.*

Comment: The solution indeed was to set a charset. I added `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` above my sql query with country codes and now they are correctly inserted in the database. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the discussion in the comments was that the charset wasn't properly set. Inserting

```
 $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

solved the problem. This is the preferred way to set the desired charset for the connection, I cite the documentation to [mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

> Note:
>
> This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using
>   mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the same character set throughout your PHP and database interaction. A few things must be checked:

1. Pick an appropriate character set.  In this case I'll assume UTF8.
2. Save your PHP file as UTF8.
3. Add a query `SET NAMES 'utf8'` to your PHP immediately after opening the connection.
4. [Set your table and column char sets to UTF8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-table.html). At the very least use `CHARSET=utf8` in your table definitions.

Comment: Don’t use `SET NAMES`, use [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset) instead.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally deleted my own comment. I have set `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` above my sql query and it works :).

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to VMai and also to Gumbo, the problem was solved.

The solution was placing to set a charset. I added `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` above my sql ($sql) query with country codes and now they are correctly inserted in the database. Thank you!